# Ignorar la parada de servicios si no estan en el servidor destino

Tags: linux, task

Os pongo en situación, estoy montando una task en Ansible que pare y deshabilite los siguientes servicios que tengo puestos en un array (diccionario):

```
services: [
  { name: 'iptables', status: 'stopped', enable: 'false' },
  { name: 'ip6tables', status: 'stopped', enable: 'false' },
  { name: 'cups', status: 'stopped', enable: 'false' },
  { name: 'smb', status: 'stopped', enable: 'false' },
  { name: 'ftp', status: 'stopped', enable: 'false' },
  { name: 'telnet', status: 'stopped', enable: 'false' },
  { name: 'nfs', status: 'stopped', enable: 'false' },
  { name: 'snmpd', status: 'stopped', enable: 'false' },
  { name: 'snmptrapd', status: 'stopped', enable: 'false' },
  { name: 'postfix', status: 'stopped', enable: 'false' }
]
```

Cuando lo ejecuto, aquellos servicios que no existen en el servidor destino, aparece lo siguiente:

```
changed: [SERVER1] => (item={u'status': u'stopped', u'enable': u'false', u'name': u'telnet'}) => {
    "changed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "arguments": "",
            "enabled": false,
            "name": "telnet",
            "pattern": null,
            "runlevel": "default",
            "sleep": null,
            "state": "stopped"
        }
    },
    "item": {
        "enable": "false",
        "name": "telnet",
        "status": "stopped"
    },
    "msg": "Service telnet not found on host, assuming it will exist on full run" }
```

Para que no aparezcan estos "changed" he añadido register y when en la task:

```
---

- name: Registro de servicios
  shell: ls -1 /etc/init.d/
  register: registrodeservicios

- name: Disable insecure services
  service:
    name: '{{ item.name }}'
    state:  '{{ item.status }}'
    enabled: '{{ item.enable }}'
  loop: "{{ services }}"
  when: item.name is registrodeservicios.stat.exists
```

Pero al ejecutar el playbook, aparece el siguiente error:

```
fatal: [SERVER1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The conditional check 'item.name is registrodeservicios.stat.exists' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no test named 'registrodeservicios.stat.exists'. String: {% if item.name is registrodeservicios.stat.exists %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/roles/osbasic/tasks/security/c17_disable_insecure_services.yml': line 7, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Disable insecure services\n  ^ here\n"
}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/osbasic.retry
```

Alguien me puede ayudar para solucionar este caso?

Muchas gracias,

David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está solucionado, en el when puse:

```
    ---

- name: Registro de servicios
  shell: ls -1 /etc/init.d/
  register: registrodeservicios
  changed_when: False

- name: Disable insecure services
  service:
    name: '{{ item.name }}'
    state:  '{{ item.status }}'
    enabled: '{{ item.enable }}'
  loop: "{{ services }}"
  when: item.name in registrodeservicios.stdout_lines
```